# Error with next/router while using Next.js, TypeScript, and Tailwind CSS in a login/register page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

I am working on a login/register page for a personal project using Next.js, TypeScript, and Tailwind CSS. However, I'm encountering an error with next/router that I can't seem to solve. I have consulted the official documentation and followed various tutorials, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here's what was supposed to happen: When I click the "Continuar" (continue) button, it should send the credentials to the API I'm using and navigate from the register page to the login page. However, when I click the button, the registration process works fine, but I receive the following error: "Error: No router instance found. You should only use next/router on the client side of your app."

Below is the code snippet I'm currently using:

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { BsEyeSlash, BsEye } from "react-icons/bs";
import Image from "next/image";

const Register = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  
  const router = useRouter();

  function addUser() {
    const user = {
      email: email,
      username: username,
      name: name,
      password: password,
    };
    
    axios
      .post(
        "http://192.168.0.72:4000/api/auth/register",
        user
      )
      .then((res) => {
        alert(res.data.data);
        router.push('./login');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  }

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <div className="box-border h-4/5 mt-1 w-72 p-4 border-1 border-green-900 shadow-2xl flex flex-col justify-start items-center mb-4">
          <Image src="/logosocial.png" width={200} height={100} alt="" />
          <label className="mt-4 text-sm">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
            className="mt-2 p-2 border-2 border-green-900"
          />
          {/* Rest of the input fields */}
          <button
            onClick={addUser}
            className="mt-5 bg-green-900 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-6 rounded"
          >
            Continuar
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="box-border h-20 mt-1 w-72 p-4 border-1 border-green-900 shadow-2xl flex flex-col justify-start items-center">
          <h1 className="mt-4" style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}>
            <div>
              Tens uma conta? ‎
              <Link className="underline text-green-900 " href="/login">
                Inicia Sessão.
              </Link>
            </div>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import `next/router` when using the app directory, import the `useRouter` hook from `next/navigation` instead.

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function YourComponent(): JSX.Element {
  const router = useRouter();
  // ...
}
```